# Batch-OCR screenshots and save their content in metadata?

Tags: macos, mac, ocr

For quite some time, I've been looking for a way to make screenshots searchable on my mac. Is there a way to batch-OCR them and then save the text with the image or index them in some way, so spotlight would be able to search through the content?

Comment: not ideal, but i use evernote to allow me to search screenshots/scans.

Comment: @booyaa quite cumbersome, no?